# Semantic segmentation without labels in a single class

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I am kind of new to semantic segmentation. I am trying to perform segmentation of images having defects.
I have the defect images annotated using a annotation tool and I created the mask for each image. I wanted to predict If an image has defect and where exactly it is located. But my problem is my defects does not look same in all the images. Example: Defects on steel- Steel breakage, erroded surface etc. I am just trying to classify if the image has defect or not and where it is located. So is it wrong to train the neural network with these all types considered as defects even though not everything lookalike?

I thought to do a binary segmentation of defect to no defect. If I am not correct how can I perform segmentation for defect and non defect images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to well define your problem and your objectives:

- If you only want to detect if your image has a defect or not, it's a **binary classification** problem and you affect a label (0 or 1) to each image.
- If you want to localise the defect approximatively (like a bounding box), it's an **object detection** problem and it can be realised with one or more classes.
- If you want to localise precisely the defect (in order to performe measures for instance) the best is **semantic segmentation** or **instance segmentation**.
- If you want to classify the defect, you will need to create classes for each defect you want to classify.

There is no magical solution because it depends of the objectives of your project. I can give you the following advices because I made an internship on a similar project :

- Look carefully at your data, if you have thousands of images it will take a long to create your semantic segmentation dataset. Be smarter by using [data augmentation techniques](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-augmentation-techniques-in-python-f216ef5eed69).
- If you want to classify the defects, be sure to have enough defects of each type to train your network. If your network only sees one defect type per epoch, it can't learn to detect it.
- Be sure that your network can detect the defects you're providing (not a scratch of two pixels for instance or alignement defects).

Performing semantic segmentation to only knows if there is a defect or not seems overkill because it's a long and complex process (rebuilding the image, memory of intermediaries images in [Unet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597), lot of computations). If you really want to apply this method, you may create a threshold to detect if the number of detected pixels as defect allows to classify the image as 'presenting a defect' or not.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to perform like if there is a defect or not and localize it precisely without any class seperation. Ofcourse I also will try multi label segmentation but I wanted to know what I tried is correct. Say for example if we have a dataset like Oxford_iit_pets. I wanted it to detect the pets and localize them without labelling them as dogs or cats and overall as pets.

Comment: The simplest way is to use semantic segmentation with two calsses (defect and no defect) and then set a threshold to classify the image as presenting the defaut. You have to be careful of the imbalance between the classes (because 'accuracy' will not be relevant - https://towardsdatascience.com/metrics-to-evaluate-your-semantic-segmentation-model-6bcb99639aa2). The 'hardest' way is to first determine if the image has a defect and then detect it, but it can show better results. The best is to try !

Comment: I did not use no defect images. its just a single class with defect parts as ground truth masks. In that the defect shapes vary so much and that is why I was confused.

Comment: And do you mean no defect class to be a ground truth mask without any labels?

Comment: Try with just one class, it can work (dogs have various shapes also) ! If it doesn't, maybe you'll have to separate in two sub classes (let say circular and  lengthways defects). Maybe instance segmentation will be more suitable also.

Comment: OK thankyou. Actually I wanted to know if my attempt with single class is correct. So i got to know that it is correct. And yeah now am working on multilabel segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

One class should be enough for your use-case. If you want to be able to distinguish between different types of defects though, you could try creating attributes for that class. So the class would be if a pixel has a defect or not, and the attribute would be breakage, eroded pixel, etc. Then you could train a model to detect a crack on the semantic class and another one to identify which type of defect it is.

Make sure to use an annotation tool that supports creating attributes. Personally, I use hasty.ai as their automation assistants are great! But I guess most tools should be able to do so.